# How can I import lib folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I've a project in Android Studio and I want import a library ZXing. I downloaded the folder not the jar but how can I import it? thanks

Comment: you want to import lib folder or lib project?

Comment: You will need the jar file to import the jar file...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate ZXing Library to Android Studio for Barcode Scanning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851512/how-to-integrate-zxing-library-to-android-studio-for-barcode-scanning)

Comment: Check this link out...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library

Comment: I downloaded the folder called zxing-master and I want import that to my project I know how import jar but not folder.

Comment: @PauloHenriqueDutra, check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow below steps:

> 1. Goto File
> 2. Click -> Import Module...
> 3. Then select you library project folder.

After importing library project.

> 1. Goto File
> 2. Click-> Project Structure
> 3. Select your main project from Module section [Left Pane]
> 4. Then click on Dependency Tab on Right Side
> 5. Click on + icon on Right Side -> Select Module Dependency -> Choose Module