# Zxing's androidtest project is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, zxing, android-studio-import

I am using Android Studio and I imported the project androidtest from [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing):

But there are some errors caused by a missing dependency.

[image: Error's print]

How to solve these dependencies? I tried to sync gradle, but not worked.

Comment: add this dependencies in gradle file... dependencies {
    compile 'cn.bingoogolapple:zxing:1.0.2'
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The androidtest is not a project for Android studio therefore your gradle file is lacking of the right dependencies.

You should take this as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27852368/2442831