# I want to add zxing to my project

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, android-studio, zxing

there are so many examples but I am still not able to add this, because this is showing different errors..

someone please tell me 
how to add [this project](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) to my project as a library. I need zxing library

please tell me how to add as a module

Comment: You just need to add the dependency in your build gradle. To get better advicr please be more specific about what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I am making a barcode scanner app.. I need library (zxing lib)., I tried so many files but no one is working.......

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851512/how-to-integrate-zxing-library-to-android-studio-for-barcode-scanning

Answer (score 0):

You can include this [library](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded),it's based `ZXing`
Add the following to your build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'   // Version 23+ is required
}
```

Comment: Now it is showing this..while sync..


Error:Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
<a href="https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy">Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle</a>

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [ZXing Android Embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/) which uses [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) internally. This library is easy to be integrated with your current Android project.

As [instructions](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/#adding-aar-dependency-with-gradle) say, you should add the following lines to your **module** `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

Note that you should have `com.android.support:appcompat` library installed. In this example version `23.1.0` of it is being used, you may change it.

Also note that if you already have a `dependencies` section in your `build.gradle` file, it's enough to add the `compile` lines to that section.

---

Alternatively you can [download the library](https://bintray.com/journeyapps/maven/download_file?file_path=com%2Fjourneyapps%2Fzxing-android-embedded%2F3.3.0%2Fzxing-android-embedded-3.3.0.aar) manually from bintray and [add it to your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506648/adding-local-aar-files-to-gradle-build-using-flatdirs-is-not-working).

Comment: Error:No cached version of com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0 available for offline mode.
<a href="toggle.offline.mode">Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project</a>



showing this and when i disable this it is showing this->>


 
(Now it is showing this..while sync)..                Error:Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle. <a href="docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/… about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle</a>

Comment: @SahityaDubey First disable 'offline mode' and then establish a live Internet connection. Android Studio needs to access `jcenter` repository and download the library.

Comment: yeah I disable this ->>

"Error:Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
<a href="https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy">Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle</a>"


...........it is still there..

Comment: @SahityaDubey Is your Android Studio connected to the Internet?

Comment: @SahityaDubey It seems your Android Studio can't access the Internet. Ok, you can alternatively [download](https://bintray.com/journeyapps/maven/download_file?file_path=com%2Fjourneyapps%2Fzxing-android-embedded%2F3.3.0%2Fzxing-android-embedded-3.3.0.aar) the library manually and add it to your project.

Comment: Thanxxx @HiI'mFrogatto   For help.... that problem has resolved... :) :)