# ZXing and Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, zxing

I used to work with ZXing (QR scanner) in Eclipse and I know how it works there. Now, I'm trying to the same thing in Android Studio. I have added dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.2.0'
}
```

I am having an issue with CaptureActivity in my manifest, since it's not recognized ("Cannot resolve symbol..").

This is in my AndroidManifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am starting QR code scanner with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

And accepting result with onActivityResult method.

**I know that there is no CaptureActivity in core library**, but where can I find it? Is there anything else I should add (like dependecies or anything similar) to my project?

I am not that familiar with Android Studio, I recently started using it.

Comment: You can find CaptureActivity here:https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java

Comment: @BensonTommy What should I do with it? Is it allowed to copy this code to my project? This project will go to production pretty soon for some client.

Comment: I have found a dependency to use: `compile 'info.vividcode.android.zxing:capture-activity:2.3.0-1.+'`

Comment: @BensonTommy thanks :D I will try it tomorrow when I arrive at my job and I'll let you know if it was ok.

Comment: @BensonTommy Everything works fine and I hope that there won't be any problems with License (https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/License-Questions). I have read it and noticed this: "One particularly contentious issue has been reuse of Barcode Scanner's user interface.".

Comment: `zxing` is `under Apache License v2.0`,read it carefully before ship it.

Comment: Got the solution for it?

Comment: You have to make your own Capture Activity using ZXing library if you wan't to use it for production version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change your code to:

ref: [Zxing scanner Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571530/zxing-scanner-android-studio/27573877#27573877)

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
integrator.initiateScan();
```